# Why does my page header have gaps around it without color?

Tags: html, css

I was trying to fill the entire `<header>` with the background color, but the problem is that when I try to view the page, instead of filling the entire `<header>` with the color, there are white color borders on top, left and right of the `<header>`. May I know the reason why the background color doesn't fill the whole `<header>` space entirely?

```css
header {
  background-color: #ECF3F3;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Food Hunt</h1>
  </header>
  <nav>
  </nav>
  <aside>
  </aside>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be caused by the margin/padding on the `body` or `html` elements, but it can also be caused by the margin on your `h1` element.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/screenmutt/2k5p5/).

```css
header {
    background-color: pink;
}

header h1 {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1>Title</h1>
</header>
```

Answer (score 4):

All HTML document by default have a margin surrounding all four corners of it. 
So you have to explicitly remove this margin every time you create a new HTML page/template.

The following can help you remove the default margin attached with the HTML pages  :

```
body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

header{
    background-color:#ECF3F3;
}
```

And this should remove the unwanted white color.

Demo : http://jsbin.com/OVAnowe/1/

Answer (score 0):

It does fill the whole header with background colour.

You are seeing the margins or padding for the body or the html elements.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in ur CSS:

```
 body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
h1 {
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
```

See the Fiddle:

**http://jsfiddle.net/SN3e3/**

Answer (score 0):

By default HTML will apply padding and a margin try this:

```
header h1{border: 0; margin: 0;}
*{border: 0; margin: 0;}
```

Any  inside of header will now render without a margin or border, the same goes for using * to apply to all elements

http://jsfiddle.net/LXAJg/

Answer (score -1):

At the top of ur css sheet add

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

This will reset the pages margin and padding properties to 0, allowing the background color property to fill the .

Comment: I don't recommend this. You'll be left with paragraphs and lists all mashed together and needing new spacing applied. Better to be more specific.

Comment: It's sort of like a light css reset.  Some developers prefer to fully reset the css defaults.  Gives them more control over every element.  Here's the css reset I always use, and may also help in this case:

https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/