# Angular4 Background Color Setup

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to make a background color to fill whole page. I have created in body , and when I am doing background-color: blue its not working as I want it to work. In other words its not filling the whole Background but only the background of things that this div contains.

```html
<body [ngStyle]="{'height': '100%', 'margin': '0'}">
  <!-- App-root represents the html code below <div [ngStyle} and so on -->
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

<div [ngStyle]="{'background-color' : 'blue', 'height': '100%'}">
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a routerLink="">Strona Główna</a></li>
          <li><a routerLink="/repertuar">Repertuar</a></li>
         <li><a routerLink="/ofirmie">O Firmie</a></li>
         <li><a routerLink="/kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </nav>
  </header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Background color is acting as follows:

[image]

Comment: Similar question has been asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20220781/fill-the-entire-header-background-with-color

Comment: unfortunatelly that answer is not helping me at all, even after I added padding:(

Comment: Have you inspected the elements on the page? Are their heights actually filling the full height of the window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your issue right now, so here's a guess:
It might work when you set `display: block` on app-root, i.e. `:host {display: block}` in your `app.component.css`

3 other solutions from the top of my head:

1) style `body` with `min-height: 100vh` instead of `height: 100%`

2) use `position: absolute` on your app-root and make it fill the screen with `bottom: 0; top: 0; right: 0; left: 0;`

3) use `display: flex` on body and `display: block; flex: 1;` on your app-root